# Write $f(x)=|x|^{\delta}-(1+|x|^{2})^{\delta/2}$ in the integral form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f(x)=|x|^{\delta}-(1+|x|^{2})^{\delta/2}$, where $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$ and $1<\delta<2$. Then how to write $f$ in the integral form by fundamental calculus. 
My thinking: I write $f(x)= c\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{(s+|x|^{2})^{1-\delta/2}}\,ds$, but the integral is singular at $t=0$ and when $x=0$. Obviously, in the original $f$, $x$ can be zero. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} \frac 1 {s^{1-\frac \delta 2}}\, ds= \frac 2 {\delta}<\infty$. The singularity does not cause any problem.